# $http.get(...).success is not a function angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, frontend

In angular js version 1.2.9 "success" function works but in 1.6 it uses "then" function which works so how can I convert the following code using then

```
artistControllers.controller('DetailsController', ['$scope', '$http','$routeParams', function($scope, $http, $routeParams) {
  $http.get('js/data.json').success(function(data) {
    $scope.artists = data;
    $scope.whichItem = $routeParams.itemId;
  });
}]);
```

Answer (score 3):

.success is deprecated for versions above 1.3. You should use .then

```
artistControllers.controller('DetailsController', ['$scope', '$http','$routeParams', function($scope, $http, $routeParams) {
  $http.get('js/data.json').then(function(data) {
    $scope.artists = data;
    $scope.whichItem = $routeParams.itemId;
  });
}]);
```

Answer (score 1):

The `.success` syntax was correct up to Angular v1.4.3.

For versions up to Angular v.1.6, you have to use `then` method. The `then()` method takes two arguments: a `success` and an `error` callback which will be called with a response object.

Using the `then()` method, attach a `callback` function to the returned `promise`.

Something like this:

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope, $http){
   $http({
      method: 'GET',
      url: 'api/url-api'
   }).then(function (success){

   },function (error){

   });
}
```

See reference [here.](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http)

`Shortcut` methods are also available.

```
$http.get('api/url-api').then(successCallback, errorCallback);

function successCallback(response){
    //success code
}
function errorCallback(error){
    //error code
}
```

The major difference between the 2 is that `.then()` call returns a `promise` (resolved with a value returned from a `callback`) while `.success()` is more traditional way of registering `callbacks` and doesn't return a `promise`.

**Solution**

```
artistControllers.controller('DetailsController', ['$scope', 
  '$http','$routeParams', function($scope, $http, $routeParams) {
    $http.get('js/data.json').then(function(data) {
      $scope.artists = data;
      $scope.whichItem = $routeParams.itemId;
    });
}]);
```

Answer (score 0):

The structure of $http has changed. Use `.then` instead of `.success`

```
$http.get('js/data.json').then(function(data){
   console.log(data);
}).catch(function(error)){
console.log(error)
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try this....

```
$http.get("http://localhost/angulartest/index.php/Items/getItems")
    .then(function (response) {

        console.log(response.data);
        $scope.records = response.data;
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Do three things

1. Replace success() with then()
2. Replace error() with catch()
3. Consider response.data not the response